# Resultset output in rows to be converted to single col output separated by comma

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to write this java procedure to display the output of this code in a single col separated by comma instead of multiples rows.
In the printOut section, I would like to combine all the output in the rows to 1 col per user. I tried using the ArrayList arr = new ArrayList() and 
Set results = new HashSet() so that i can get all the row values in an array seperated by comma as shown in the expected output.

```
         ResultSet group=(ResultSet)Groups.getFieldValue(USER_GROUP_RESULTSET);//Gets all the user groups for the user
        printOut("Groupscount:"+group.getRowCount()); //Counts the # of user groups user is assigned to for printing purpose only
        group.moveFirst();
        while(!group.isEof()) {  //For all the user groups,list the user name and another col with all user groups separated by comma instead of individual rows.
        String groupname1= group.getFieldValueString(USER_GROUP); // fetches the user group name in the string. Do i need to use array here?
        printOut(USER+";"+groupname1); // It displays the output row wise
        group.moveNext();

                }
```

Actual output:
User1;XYZ
User1;ABC

Expected output:
User1; XYZ,ABC

Comment: Start by indenting the code correctly to be able to read your code and understand its structure.

Comment: Sorry ! just updated only the code I am stuck with.

Comment: Probably your `groupOut` prints a newline. I'm just guessing here cause I don't know what data you get from your `ResultSet`. If you have multiple rows with the same first column and you want to combine them, you need to do more than just printing, you'd need to create a hash map where you use the first column as key, then concatenate the other data while iterating over `group`. Then iterate over that map and print the accumulated values. If this doesn't get you on the right track, please [edit] your question and include a [mcve]. You may also want to read [ask].

Comment: You have understood correctly. I did not want to put too much code that is not relevant to the question. I had missed 1 piece of code that I have added now String groupname1= group.getFieldValueString(USER_GROUP); So 1st col remains the same for every iteration and i need to list all the groups for that 1 col value. Can you please post an example how to use hash map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move printOut outside of the while loop

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
while(!group.isEof()) {
String groupname1=group.getFieldValueString(USER_GROUP);
sb.append(";"+groupname1);
group.moveNext();
}

printOut(USER+sb.toString());
```